# Expected argument of type "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile", "array" given

Tags: php, symfony

I have upload multiple file but I have this error:

> Expected argument of type "Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile", "array" given

I use DataTransformerInterface for convert content input file to array.

Entity Document:

```
<?php

    namespace AppBundle\Entity;

    use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;
    use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;

    /**
     * Document
     *
     * @ORM\Table(name="document")
     * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\DocumentRepository")
     */
    class Document
    {
        /**
         * @var int
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
         * @ORM\Id
         * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
         */
        private $id;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $name;

        /**
         * @var string
         *
         * @ORM\Column(name="path", type="string", length=255)
         */
        private $path;

        /**
         * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
         */
        private $file;


        /**
         * Get id
         *
         * @return integer 
         */
        public function getId()
        {
            return $this->id;
        }


        /**
         * Sets file.
         *
         * @param UploadedFile $file
         */
        public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
        {
            $this->file = $file;
        }

        /**
         * Get file.
         *
         * @return UploadedFile
         */
        public function getFile()
        {
            return $this->file;
        }


        /**
         * Set name
         *
         * @param string $name
         * @return Document
         */
        public function setName($name)
        {
            $this->name = $name;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get name
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getName()
        {
            return $this->name;
        }

        /**
         * Set path
         *
         * @param string $path
         * @return Document
         */
        public function setPath($path)
        {
            $this->path = $path;

            return $this;
        }

        /**
         * Get path
         *
         * @return string 
         */
        public function getPath()
        {
            return $this->path;
        }

         public function getAbsolutePath()
        {
            return null === $this->path
                ? null
                : $this->getUploadRootDir().'/'.$this->path;
        }

        public function getWebPath()
        {
            return null === $this->path
                ? null
                : $this->getUploadDir().'/'.$this->path;
        }

        protected function getUploadRootDir()
        {
            // the absolute directory path where uploaded
            // documents should be saved
            return __DIR__.'/../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
        }

        protected function getUploadDir()
        {
            // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
            // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
            return 'uploads';
        }

        public function upload()
    {
        // the file property can be empty if the field is not required
        if (null === $this->getFile()) {
            return;
        }

        // use the original file name here but you should
        // sanitize it at least to avoid any security issues

        // move takes the target directory and then the
        // target filename to move to
        $this->getFile()->move(
            $this->getUploadRootDir(),
            $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName()
        );
        // set the path property to the filename where you've saved the file
        $this->path = $this->getFile()->getClientOriginalName();

        // clean up the file property as you won't need it anymore
        $this->file = null;
    }
    }
```

Code FileTransformer.php:

```
<?php 

    namespace AppBundle\Form;

    use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
    use AppBundle\Entity\Document;
    use Doctrine\Common\Persistance\ObjectManager;
    use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;
    use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

    class FileTransformer implements DataTransformerInterface {

        /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */

    private $manager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $manager){
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

    public function transform($value) {
            if ($value != "") {
            return var_dump("error");
        }
            return $value;
    }

    protected function getUploadRootDir()
        {
            // the absolute directory path where uploaded
            // documents should be saved
            return __DIR__.'/../../../web/'.$this->getUploadDir();
        }

        protected function getUploadDir()
        {
            // get rid of the __DIR__ so it doesn't screw up
            // when displaying uploaded doc/image in the view.
            return 'uploads';
        }

    public function reverseTransform($files)
        {
            $Documents = [];
            foreach($files as $file){

                $Document = new Document();
                $Document->setPath($file->getClientOriginalName());
                $Document->setName($file->getClientOriginalName());
                 $this->manager->persist($Document);
                 $file->move(
            $this->getUploadRootDir(),
            $file->getClientOriginalName()
        );
                $this->manager->flush();

                $Documents[] = $Document;

            }

    var_dump("2");

            return $Documents;
        }

    }
```

Code DocumentType.php:

```
<?php

    namespace AppBundle\Form;

    use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
    use AppBundle\Form\FileTransformer;
    use Doctrine\Common\Persistance\ObjectManager;
    use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManagerInterface;
    use Symfony\Component\Form\DataTransformerInterface;
    use AppBundle\Entity\Document;
    use Symfony\Bridge\Doctrine\Form\DataTransformer\CollectionToArrayTransformer;


    class DocumentType extends AbstractType
    {

        /**
     * @var EntityManagerInterface
     */

    private $manager;

    public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $manager){
        $this->manager = $manager;
    }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
        {
            $builder->add('name')->add('file', 'file',array('multiple' => 'multiple'));
            $builder->get('file')->addModelTransformer(new FileTransformer($this->manager),true);

        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
        {
            $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => 'AppBundle\Entity\Document',

            ));
        }

        /**
         * {@inheritdoc}
         */
        public function getBlockPrefix()
        {
            return 'appbundle_document';
        }

    }
```

Code DefualtController.php:

```
    public function uploadAction(Request $request)
        {
                $document = new Document();
                $form = $this->createForm(DocumentType::class, $document);


    $form->handleRequest($request);


    return $this->render('default/upload.html.twig',array('form'=>$form->createView()));

        }
```

Comment: Please provide minimum example reproducing your problem, try to spot what part of the code is throwing the error.

Comment: @ymoreau i did'nt any part of code is throwing the error but maybe in function setFile

Comment: Bug in setFile but I haven't resolve bug ..

Comment: Any help please ...